# what is the recommended Cloud Firestore location for Egypt and the middle east countries?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was starting a new firestore database and actually I didn't know what GCP resource location that's suitable for my target audience in Egypt. Any help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From looking at the available Firestore regions at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations

Your closest region would be located in Europe:

```
Europe
europe-west2    London
europe-west3    Frankfurt
europe-west6    Zürich
```

You can also try [gcping](http://www.gcping.com/) to test latencies to different Google Cloud regions.

Comment: europe-west6 is the best for Egypt, Median Latency 59 ms

Comment: GCPing is so userful, ty for that

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing how high/low ping to Egypt would be, I'd suggest to deploy to Israel:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/infrastructure/new-google-cloud-region-in-israel
This should be at least 100ms difference, compared to Germany or Switzerland.
For Firestore `europe-central2` Warsaw might also be closer.
One would have to measure and compare.
It seems one can only run the Firestore in the EU, while there's no ME location available.